# Eigen rowwise multiplication of two matrices

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to do a rowwise multiplication between two matrices.

The dimensions are Nx3 and Nx1 and the output should be Nx3.

I saw several related answers, but they are trying to do dot project, which could not solve my problem.

My attempt is

```
int n = 5000;  
MatrixXf A = MatrixXf::Random(n,3);  
MatrixXf B = MatrixXf::Random(n,1);  
MatrixXf output = A.array()*B.array();//dimension should be (n,3)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html#TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcastingBroadcasting

Comment: Output is leads to error: https://godbolt.org/z/M8MToqYnv

Comment: @MarekR thanks, this is indeed a good testing tool... One of the stupid solution I can come up with is using replicate(). So in the previous example, change B.array() to B.replicate(1,A.cols()).array(); this works.

Comment: If you make `B` a `VectorXf`, you can also do `A.array().colwise()*B.array()`.

Comment: @chtz ah, I see, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the n by 1 matrix as a vector as follows:

```
int n = 5000;  
Eigen::MatrixXf A = MatrixXf::Random(n,3); 
Eigen::VectorXf B = MatrixXf::Random(n,1);  

Eigen::MatrixXf result 
=A.array().colwise()*B.array();
```